# How to update a website while page is running in codeigniter using godaddy

Tags: php, codeigniter, updates

I am still looking for the best solution on how to update a website using a godaddy shared hosting. I have solutions of my own but I think these are still not good practice.

My solution is to put a message on the page which contains "Site is under maintenance." inside the index.php so that when user visited the site, they will be informed of it. But, I think, this is not good since, I observe on other sites, they are updating the files but do not put any text to alert the users.

Also, I tried to upload the new files direct to my site without an alert message, but, I received errors since more users are already using and submitting forms.

What is the best solution for this, to upload new updates while site is running?

Comment: Those other sites you are referring to are most likely using a vcs. I'm not sure you can do that in a shared hosting environment.

Comment: what is a vcs @Kisaragi

Comment: a version control system (git,svn etc)